# Renderizar vista nativa definida en Java sobre aplicación React Native

Tags: java, android, typescript, react-native, sdk

Estoy intentando renderizar una vista nativa definida en java dentro de una aplicación React Native. Para implementar esto me estoy guiando de la documentación oficial de React Native: [Link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-components-android)

Cuando renderizo alguna vista propia de android como un Textview o un Button no tengo mayores problemas porque logro visualizarla, pero cuando intento renderizar una vista customizada que proviene de un SDK que estoy utilizando no logro visualizarla.

El SDK que estoy usando toma datos (HTML) de un server específico y los renderiza dentro de una vista. Se utiliza para desplegar anuncios personalizados en aplicaciones nativas de Android y IOS.

Mi código es el siguiente:

***MyCustomView.java:***

```
package com.myapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.sas.mkt.mobile.sdk.ads.SASCollectorAd;

public class MyCustomView extends LinearLayout {
    public MyCustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        this.setPadding(16,16,16,16);
        this.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F0BA02"));

        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setText("This is a TEST from a Native View");

        SASCollectorAd myAd = new SASCollectorAd(context);
        myAd.load("SpotMobile_ID”, null);

        this.addView(textView);
        this.addView(myAd);
    }
}
```

En el código de arriba, `SASCollectorAd` es una clase del SDK que estoy utilizando.

***MyCustomViewManager.java:***

```
package com.myapp;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.SimpleViewManager;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext;

public class MyCustomViewManager extends SimpleViewManager<MyCustomView> {
    public static final String REACT_CLASS = "MyCustomViewManager";
    ReactApplicationContext mCallerContext;

    public MyCustomViewManager(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        mCallerContext = reactContext;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return REACT_CLASS;
    }

    @Override
    public MyCustomView createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext context) {
        return new MyCustomView(context);
    }
}
```

***MyAppPackage.java:***

```
package com.myapp;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MyAppPackage implements ReactPackage {

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Arrays.<ViewManager>asList(
                new MyCustomViewManager(reactContext)
        );
    }

    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();
        modules.add(new SharedPreferencesModule(reactContext));
        modules.add(new OpenAppModule(reactContext));
        modules.add(new AdditionalPermissionsModule(reactContext));
        modules.add(new CI360Module(reactContext));
        return modules;
    }
}
```

Desde el lado de typescript tengo:

***MyCustomView.tsx:***

```
import React from 'react';
import { Dimensions, requireNativeComponent } from 'react-native';

const MyCustomViewManager = requireNativeComponent('MyCustomViewManager');

const MyCustomView = () => {
    return (
        <MyCustomViewManager 
            style={{ 
                width: Dimensions.get('screen').width, 
                height: 100 
            }} 
        />
    )
}

export default MyCustomView;
```

Adjunto un screenshot de lo que mi app está renderizando:

[image: Screenshot]

Como se puede ver en el rectángulo naranja, el Textview es renderizado ok pero no logro ver la vista del SDK (myAd) sobre dicho rectángulo.
Debo desplegar un anuncio en un footer sobre una determinada pantalla de la app. Ese footer está representado por el rectángulo naranja.

No puedo compartir mucho más código que el anterior puesto que es de una app comercial que se encuentra vigente. Por eso cambié el nombre del package name y oculté las vistas con cuadrados de colores.

He intentado también utilizar un fragment para mostrar la información pero funciona no del todo bien, es decir, alguna veces puedo ver el html renderizado en la app pero me rompe totalmente las otras vistas. Aparece un cuadrado blanco que me tapa más de la mitad de la pantalla y a veces me hace crashear la app con un error de que no encuentra el fragment. Como dije anteriormente siempre siguiendo la documentación oficial.

Espero que puedan brindarme algunos tips para resolver esto.

Muchas gracias.